# Array sorting in Front-end or Back-end

Tags: javascript, frontend, backend

I am implementing a RESTful API that returns an array. I want to know if it will be more efficient to sort the array in descending order in my backend code or in the javascript?

Comment: Is the data coming from a database, and how big is the dataset?

Comment: For the most part, it will be faster on the backend if you are using a database such as MySQL, but if you expect lots of traffic, could be a bottleneck.

Comment: @Brennan yes it is coming from the database, and i only pull up 20 rows

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your API will be used by *n* clients. Performance-wise it would make sense to have each client do the sorting on their own instead of having the server do it for all the *n* clients. Simply, less CPU work for the server.

Furthermore, whether the result needs to be sorted or not depends on the nature of the application using the data. Let the application decide that. Some interfaces allow the user to decide what to sort by, thereby convenient to do it locally (without waiting for a background HTTP call).

However I would not overthink the performance part before you actually have a performance problem. It could also be that the data sorting is not really costly or the sorting has already been done depending on how information is kept internally (in DBMS-s, for example).

**Edit**

With up to 20 rows without sorting, it really makes no important difference - make the API implementing developers' life easier and do the small sorting on the frontend side.

Comment: Agree. The backend should return array of objects that can be sorted by different properties such as `created_at`, `order`, `title` etc... The front end sorts the objects via these properties. So.. the front end says "here are object, and how to sort them" the fontend listens and sorts via these properties.

Comment: Yeh small lists no difference. Bigger ones the initial request for the data would have the orderBy param. Often BE would return 1 page to the FE but there may be hundreds & thousands in the DB. Changing the order would require a new BE request as it would likely load entirely different posts for that page.

Answer (score 10):

I would actually try to hand it off to the database. Write the query where the array returned from the DB is already sorted. The most computing power and most efficient sorting is probably on the DB.

This goes to sorting, filtering in general IMO.

Answer (score 7):

Depends on from where data come, how much of it do you have, and what goals you want to achieve.

Frontend based solution is cost less server CPU but could become terrible user experience. Imagine an array of 100000 features sorted in IE installed on old PC? It could hang the browser.

So if you have hot much data to process or CPU economy on server is important for you use frontend, otherwise backend.

Comment: have you already rendered 100000 features on a single page ? that's quite a lot of information

Comment: Yes i did. more than 100000 geopoints and lines on single map canvas.

Comment: I feel like that doesn't make sense. If you're doing enough work to hang the client, it would still be a lot of work for the server. Hardware doesn't make that much difference unless you're comparing it to pre-pentium or something. If something will hang the client but be effortless for the server, it would come down to algorithmic efficiency, not hardware.

Comment: It's hardly any work for the server as it doesn't need to render anything. The browser on the other hand takes a lot of CPU use.

Answer (score 4):

A RESTful API is built for the purpose of a developer using it. The values it returns, the errors it presents, even the headers are all part of the "user experience" a developer has when using your API.

Now you need to weigh that against performance concerns. Is it potentially lots of data? Can you limit that data through paging, etc.? Doing a long sort operation on your server can, in unchecked situations, provide a severely degraded experience for not only that user but also others.

That said, a server typically has a lot more power for sorting and even (using the right language/algorithm) could provide a multithreaded approach to the problem. So if you're not worried about performance impacts server side, in almost all cases I would do it on the server.

Answer (score 4):

Think about it this way .. Do you want the server to do the work, or the individual's browser ...  So efficiency comes down to THEIR system hardware and software ..  Anytime you can not "pawn off" the load to the browser, it's going to be slightly more overhead on the server .. However, there are less questions to be had  -- The short answer is nobody knows, since you can't know all aspects of your clients system.

With that said, it's just array parsing.  With larger (by large, I mean HUGE) datasets ...  What you're asking might be slightly noticeable between server-side and client side processing of the array.  But if it's not "HUGE" --  It is most likely to be six one way half dozen the other from a performance stand point.

Best practice, in my opinion, is to keep the code where you can control the overhead.  Server-side.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your needs. If you have small amount of data, you can do all in FE, so user will have not to load the same array for different sortings.

With a lot of data and pagination it's better to do it on back-end, of course.

Comment: You should also consider bandwidth, making requests to the server and transferring lots of data is also costly. If the server handles lots of requests for many clients, that might be a problem.